# ¿Por qué se tradujo "I'm voting to close" como "Voto para" en lugar de "Voto por"?

Tags: discusión, traducciones, transifex

No quiero echar culpas ni nada.. no es la idea, solo que la traducción no me parece del todo correcta:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because

[está traducido en Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/131532786?key=5d9e56f7d5348212fa47070a7d735a5f) como

> Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque

¿No debería ser así?

> Voto POR cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque

(énfasis en POR mío)

No quise tocar la traducción hasta estar seguro que no es un modismo mío (y el resto lo entiende correctamente).

### Edicion

(Explicado por una periodista)
El voto POR hace hincapié en la acción de tu eleccìon. En la OPCION que preferis entre otras. La pregunta  sería para saber que va: para qué o quién votas?
Respuesta: Voto por tal cosa.

El voto PARA hace hincapie en el motivo. Entonces la pregunta es: para que votas? (Cual es tu objetivo de voto?)
Respuesta: voto para tal cosa.

Comment: Acuerdo... esperemos a ver el término usado en otros lados

Comment: A mí el "para" me chirría.

Comment: Yo creo que sería una buena pregunta para un *cross-post* en [spanish.se]... Así fedorqui lo toma mejor

Comment: Creo que la palabra Voto se la puede confundir con un sustantivo. Yo pienso que sería mejor, _Estoy votando para_, pero cada uno tiene su opinión.

Comment: Estas votando para que ocurra que cosa??? ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Me refiero a que decir solamente, ***Voto***, es solo un objeto o una cosa. De otro modo, se puede aclarar con un _Yo voto_, o _Dejo un voto_. Es irrelevante el objetivo o motivo del voto.

Answer (score 5):

Las dos formas son correctas

"para" tiene sentido si lo que se quiere decir es "con la finalidad de"

"por" tiene sentido si lo que se quiere decir es que se escoge una opción entre varias

Comment: Exactamente, así lo pensé yo. Ambas me parecen correctas.

Comment: @fedorqui estoy seguro de que ambas son válidas, y tiene sentido desde lo formal del lenguaje inclinarse por "para". Pero hay algo de usos y costumbres que me hace preferir el "por". Lo siento más *natural*.

Comment: @Mariano claro, a mí me suenan bien las dos también. Si usé _para_ fue con el sentido de acortamiento de la frase larga: _Mi voto va para cerrar esta pregunta..._. No protestaré si se cambia, al final tiene que sonar natural a la mayor cantidad de gente.

Comment: @fedorqui nunca cambiaria un texto que tradujiste, sin antes preguntar, debatir y sobre todo preguntarte a vos :)

Comment: @gbianchi jaja, me sonroja la deferencia hacia mis traducciones :P Como en Spanish.SE hay gente muy potente, les traslado la duda y así aprenemos todos :) [¿Cuál es la mejor manera de traducir “I'm voting to close as off-topic…”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24031/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui luego de la lucha encarnizada en SL, podemos decir que deberia ser por? (me encanto como se tomaron el tema en serio y dieron respuestas muy bien fundamentadas).

Comment: @gbianchi jajaja pues gana _por_ por goleada. Ahora bien, hay sugerencias muy interesantes para reescribir la frase completamente, así como repensar la forma que decimos _off topic_ (no relacionado). Resumiendo: sugiere _por_ sin problema, el resto de "batallas" ya las abro en breve jeje